# Facebook ImagePicker has no member title

Tags: facebook, swift4.1

I got an example from internet that was using:

```
GBHFacebookImagePicker.pickerConfig.title = "Album"
```

But when I compile it results a compile error: "Value of type 'GBHFacebookPickerConfig' has no member 'texttitle'

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @WizKid Thank you for your question but I already found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, due to updated pod the correct way right now to set title is:

```
GBHFacebookImagePicker.pickerConfig.textConfig.localizedTitle = "Album title"
```